# How to fix "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__builtin__' " in pycharm

Tags: python

How to fix the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__builtin__'
```

in Pycharm while importing all identifiers in the `dir()` function?

```
import __builtin__
print(dir(__builtin__))
```

Comment: It would greatly help if you could add more information, what version of python you are using. Also is it builtins or builtin?

Comment: Python 3.7.4 and its builtin

Comment: Is `builtin` you own module? Because the module that's part of the Python standard library is named `builtins`.

Comment: No builtin is not my own module, but after changing to builtins then it works. Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For python 3, I believe it should be builtins and not builtin. The docs are here -> https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html

```
import builtins
print(dir(builtins))
```

For Python 2.7 it is/was

```
import __builtin__
```

Comment: Running **pip install future** fixed this error for me.
For compatibility with Python2.7, I think the package future should be added to the install_requires in setup.py (hopefully this is also compatible with Python3?).

Comment: future package is already installed. But changing it to  builtins works for me